# LINQ to DATASET update with a stored procedure

Tags: linq, dataset, linq-to-dataset

I have used LINQ to SQL with a update stored procedure to update databases in the past. I wanted to know if there is anything similar in LINQ to Dataset

An example of the LINQ to SQL Update:

```
Dim lqUpdate = lqUpdate.sprocUpdate(ColumnName, NewValue, ID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataSets are completely disconnected entities, so you won't find any way from a DataSet or DataTable to a stored proc, but the ADO.Net equivalent of a Linq DataContext is the TableAdapter, which does have support for stored procs.